# Matlab "diff" in F# (subtract element by element)

Tags: matlab, f#

There is a [diff](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) function in MATLAB, that computes difference between elements in vector (or matrix, but it is not the case now).

```
X = [1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21];
Y = diff(X)
```

Results in: `0     1     1     2     3     5     8`

I came up with F# solution:

```
let x =[1;1;2;3;5;8;13;21]
let diff x = List.map2 (-) (x|> List.tail) (x|> List.take ((x|>List.length) - 1))

diff x
```

which results in same List, but I feel there **should be a better way how to do difference** in F#? Is there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's `List.pairwise : 'T list -> ('T * 'T) list` which gives you a list of consecutive pairs of items.

```
let x =[1;1;2;3;5;8;13;21]

let diff x =
    x |> List.pairwise |> List.map (fun (x, y) -> y - x)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  Thnx

Comment: This could be marked as inline, to make the function more generic.

Answer (score 1):

Working with sequences instead of lists there is a compact solution:

```
let diff x = Seq.map2 (-) (Seq.skip 1 x) x
```

This would not work with lists because `List.map2` requires its arguments to have the same length. `Seq.map2` does not have that requirement.

For your specific case you could do:

```
[1;1;2;3;5;8;13;21] |> diff |> List.ofSeq
```

if you want the result to be a list.